# Differentiability of compositions of non differentiable functions at a point.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

> If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are differentiable functions at all points in $[a,b]$ except a one point (c) in the interval and continuous everywhere on $[a,b]$. Then it is guaranteed that $f(g(x))$ is differentiable wherever $f$ and $g$ are differentiable but is there an example for which $f(g(x))$ is also differentiable at c . Or can it be proven that something like this can’t happen?

---

It is true that if they are nowhere differentiable then it is impossible to create an example but is it possible to create an example for such a case? 
 What about 2 points, 3 points , infinitely many?

Comment: The function $g(x)=x^{1/3}$ is not differentiable at $x=0$ but if we let $f(y)=y^3$ then $g\circ f(y)=y$, and this is differentiable everywhere. Does this answer the question?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro but $y^3$ is differentiable everywhrere

Comment: I see. What about $g(x)=\lvert x \rvert$ and $$f(y)=\begin{cases} 1, & y\ge 0, \\ 0, & y<0?\end{cases}$$ We have that $f\circ g(x)=1$, and both functions are not differentiable at the origin. (Oh, but $f$ is not continuous. Then replace it by $$f(y)=\begin{cases} y, & y\ge 0, \\ 0, & y<0.\end{cases}$$ Now it should work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not even guaranteed that $f\circ g$ is differentiable wherever $f$ and $g$ are.

For example, let $f(x) = |x-1|$ and $g(x)=2|x-1|$, which are continuous and differentiable at all points in $[0,2]$ except for $x=1$. But $f(g(x))$ is not differentiable in $x=1/2$ nor $x=3/2$:

[image]

The other way around is also possible (example by @Vivaan Daga). Let $f(x)=x^-$ (notation for the [negative part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_and_negative_parts) of a function) and $g(x)=|x|$. Both are continuous everywhere and differentiable everywhere except in $x=0$. But $f(g(x))=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, so $f\circ g$ is differentiable everywhere.

Comment: f has to be differentiable at f(g)

Comment: but in this example how it is proven that if f and g is not differentiable at a point then there exist an example where (f(g(x)))'  exist at the point ?

Comment: would an example by g(x)=|x| and f(x) =| x |for x<0 and 0 for x>0 so both are not differentiable at zero but f(g(x))=0 is differentiable at zero.

Comment: Well, maybe my answer should be a comment rather than an answer. But I wanted to add the picture :)

Comment: in the example should not f(x) for x>0 be 0

Comment: See the link for the definition of the negative part of a function: $x^-=-x=|x|$ for $x<0$ and $x^-=0$ for $x\ge0$.